# Build Angular + docker - Why you need node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, docker

I want to create a Docker image with an Angular project.
I run the command "ng build" and the project is built in the dist folder.

I have seen a lot of tutorials on how to run an Angular project in docker. All tutorials say and show that you need to add node.js to the Docker image.

Example:

```
services:
   app:
     image: node:18-alpine
```

I don’t understand why add node.js if you can build the project, add it to the image from the dist folder along with Nginx and the project will work.

Can you please explain why adding node.js to a Docker image?

I apologize if the question really seemed stupid to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need Node.JS to build the Angular project. You do not need it to serve the build files from the dist folder, if these are just static assets. Any webserver capable of serving static files will do.

Some thoughts:

However: For a production image, you probably want reproducible builds, that do not depend on a "correct" build on the Docker host.

- So for development: build on the host if you like.
- For production:

1. Use a build step with a Node image and build the Angular application.
2. Copy the built files (the dist directory) in a seperate build step to a desired destination.
3. Serve the files with any webserver.

Minimal prod example:

```
#stage 1

FROM node:latest as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod

#stage 2

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist/your-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: "*For production: add Node to the Image (or use a Node.Js image) and build the application there.*" - I would advice against this and suggest to use a multistage docker build. This way, we can have a clean production image, only cotaining the software needed. Keeps the final image smaller as well.

Comment: @Turing85 Nice one!

Comment: can some1 explain me why u need docker to build angular app at all? I mean build should first install node, then run install & build, and then u create docker image -- or this is just about using docker to install npm?

Comment: Thank you so much, but I didn't ask to show you how to do it because I know how to do it. I asked to explain why it is necessary to add node.js if it is possible to use without node.js. What you have shown, I hope it helps someone.

Comment: And also, you are using outdated commands that are not valid.